# session null Error with Selenium RC

Tags: null, selenium-rc

```
Firefox version - 12.0

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

selenium-remote-control-1.0.3
```

I have strated the server

when I run following code from Eclipse I am unable to open firefox

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://bing.com");
        selenium.setSpeed("5000");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.windowFocus();
        selenium.open("/");
```

I get following error which says that session null

I want to know how to resolve this .Is this browser compatibility issue?

```
00:03:35.989 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.2-b06
00:03:35.989 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
00:03:35.989 INFO - v0.9.2 [2006], with Core v0.8.3 [1879]
00:03:36.052 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
00:03:36.052 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
00:03:36.052 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
00:03:36.052 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
00:03:36.083 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
00:03:36.083 INFO - Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@72e3b895
00:04:10.692 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
00:04:10.692 INFO - Command request: setSpeed[2000, ] on session null
00:04:10.692 INFO - Got result: OK on session null
00:04:10.708 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox, http://gmail.com, ] on session null
00:04:10.786 INFO - Launching session 50708
00:04:10.895 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
00:08:40.713 INFO - Command request: setSpeed[5000, ] on session null
00:08:40.713 INFO - Got result: OK on session null
00:08:40.728 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox, http://bing.com, ] on session null
00:08:40.728 INFO - Launching session 320728
00:08:40.837 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
```

Comment: why are you using such an old version of Selenium? Maybe upgrading might help...

Comment: Which is the latest RC version??

Comment: You can get the latest RC via the usual [`WebDriver`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) downloads. Selenium RC is included alongside with WebDriver. Just make sure you're getting the "server" or "server-standalone" versions to be able to start a RC server.